# ag-grid custom dropdown filter not refreshing the GUI of the filter once getGUI is called

Tags: filtering, ag-grid

I am trying to create the excel type filtering on ag-grid.

When user selects the checkbox and click on apply filter i am getting the result in the grid but when user types in something in search input box, the dropdown filter items are not reflecting , even though when i console the DOM , DOM has u[dated value but its not reflecting on UI.

Comment: once getGUI is called after that on which event we can refresh the data inside the filter dropdown?

Comment: can you recreate your issue in plunkr or stackblitz?